# Debug the program using preprocessed file output?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, c-preprocessor

Let say I have a file that has a lot of preprocessor macros that generate loads of code. Normally when debugging such a file I wouldn't be able to step into macroses like functions as debugger does not have line number information. On the other hand it is possible to generate a preprocessed file using /P directive to the compiler, which will result in a file that contains all generated code and no macros.

Is it possible to make Visual Studio use preprocessed file for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution (not very convenient though) is to copy the preprocessed file back to the source file and compile it again. One must remember to generate the processed file without line numbers and to keep the original source code somewhere.